# Can a character who is immune to mind-affecting effects benefit from the Craven feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, immunities

The Craven feat, which provides bonus damage on sneak attacks, has an unusual prerequisite:

> Cannot be immune to fear

If a character is immune to mind-affecting effects (such as via a [Mind Blank](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mindBlank.htm) spell), can they still receive Craven's benefit?  My understanding is that immunity to mind-affecting would prevent most (or perhaps all?) fear effects, but I'm uncertain if it's the same thing as being "immune to fear."

Comment: It may not seem like it, but you may be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110875/8610)

Comment: Oh gosh I'd forgotten about that question, and just how convoluted the "are all Fear effects mind-affecting, or only attacks" issue really was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Technically*, this is debatable. *Technically*, the rules say that fear *attacks* are always mind-affecting—leaving room for fear *effects* that are not fear *attacks*, so would not necessarily be mind-affecting, and so in theory, there could be fear effects that someone with mind-affecting immunity is still subject to.

In practice, it is almost-certain that the authors were using attack and effect interchangeably, and that all fear effects are definitively mind-affecting, and so fear immunity is a subset of mind-affecting immunity—which means that mind-affecting immunity is fear immunity (and then some). I doubt you will find many, if any, DMs, who will buy this argument and allow someone with immunity to mind-affecting effects take Craven.

All *that* said, on balance, the inability to get mind-affecting immunity is a **huge** drawback to the Craven feat. To the point that, at higher levels when a rogue should be considering a source of *mind blank*, as important as the damage bonus from Craven is, sooner or later the immunity to mind-affecting is more important.

So that leads us to a question: is it a good thing that Craven eventually becomes a *negative* effect, and so high-level rogues avoid it? On the one hand, Craven is a **large** damage bonus for rogues and the like, far better than almost any other feat would be for your typical two-weapon fighting rogue. Even more so when you’re looking at a multiclassed character whose sneak attack isn’t as good as a single-classed rogue. If it didn’t have that drawback, every sneak attacking character ever would always take the feat. That’s bad—feats should be options, not mandatory. Something that’s too good becomes *centralizing*, since everyone takes it.

However, another thing to consider is, sneak attackers simply deal less damage, a *lot* less damage, than other martial characters. The benefits of two-handed weapons, charging, and so on are all far larger than sneak attack, *even with Craven*. So if rogues and the like are avoiding Craven because of its drawback, they are then *even worse off* than they would be. From this perspective, Craven-without-drawbacks might be considered better for balance—sure, every sneak attacker will always want to take it, but at least once they do they’ll be *closer* in damage. Consider: Power Attack can deal literally twice the damage that Craven does, and the attack penalty is **far** easier to deal with than Craven’s ban on mind-affecting immunity.

So while almost-no DM is ever going to buy the argument the *attack vs. effect* argument for allowing someone with mind-affecting immunity to take Craven, some DMs might consider allowing it as a houserule. It may be worth asking.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw your attention to the epic level skill use of diplomacy for an approximate comparison. The fanatic condition states:

> Treat the fanatic attitude as a mind-affecting enchantment effect for
>   purposes of immunity, save bonuses, or being detected by the Sense
>   Motive skill. Since it is nonmagical, it can’t be dispelled; however,
>   any effect that suppresses or counters mind-affecting effects will
>   affect it normally.

It's not a magical compulsion; it's purely mundane, yet it would be suppressed by a *mind blank* spell. If your argument is to differentiate between fear effects and say fear as a psychological condition using fanatic as a precedent for parallel, you would also be required to acknowledge that *mind blank* renders the character immune to fear in the literal meaning of the term.